# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'T_PreviewDetails' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I got the above error while trying to insert values to  the table 'T_PreviewDetails' through below code.

```
 T_PreviewDetails objprevdet = new T_PreviewDetails();
 objprevdet.Title = "preview";
 objprevdet.Preview_ID = objprev.ID;
 objprevdet.SelectionListDetails_ID = objSelectListDetails.ID;
 objprevdet.PreviewStatus_ID = 2;
 context.T_PreviewDetails.Add(objprevdet);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

But direct inserting values to the database works fine.Also in 'T_PreviewDetails.cs'

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] is entered.
```